# Call https wsdl from php 5.2.0

Tags: php, soap, https, wsdl, openssl

I need to call a https wsdl service from php. The original message error was:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://xxxxx.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://xxxx.svc?wsdl"

I did this:

1. I actived in php.ini: extension=php_openssl.dll
2. I copied: libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in System32
3. My version of PHP is 5.3.9

And the message error says this:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://xxx.svc?xsd=xsd0''

I read a lot of post with the similar errors, but anyone helps me.

I need your hepl

Comment: Does that schema exist? Can you access it via a browser from the server?  Also, is the error a copy/paste?  One instance shows http, the other shows https?

Comment: Does that schema exist? Yes it exists, 
Can you access it via a browser from the server? Yes, If I write the direction in the browser, the service works
One instance shows http, the other shows https? It is weird, because when disable extension=php_openssl.dll appears the original error with https, but when I active the extension=php_openssl.dll the message error changes and appears http

Comment: Ah, read those again . . . the second is an error parsing the schema, the first is an error getting the WSDL.  I'm guessing the schema doesn't exist?